# Is the set $S={\left\{ x \in \mathbb{Q}:-\sqrt2 < x < \sqrt2 \right\}}$ open in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I was reading Pubg's book on real analysis and in the second chapter while introducing clopen sets he gave an example that the set $S={\left\{ x \in\mathbb{Q}:-\sqrt2 < x < \sqrt2 \right\}}$ is both open and close in $\mathbb{Q}$ but neither open nor close in $\mathbb{R}$.

So the reason it seems to me that it is an open set is that, we can always find a small open ball near the edge of two end point which include all the points of that set. And we can not find any point in the region $ -\sqrt2 < x < \sqrt2$ for which it's neighborhood does not contain any points of the set $S$. So it is an open set.

While typing it another thing I remembered is that an open set have to contain all the points around its neighborhood and because the element of the set $S$ is in $\mathbb{Q}$ and there are many points in the region $ -\sqrt2 < x < \sqrt2$ (in $\mathbb{R}$) that $S$ does not contain so there would be some $x$ for which $N_r(x)$ does not contain all the neighborhood points. Is that the reason $S$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I am not sure what you question is.  Saying $S$ is both open and closed in $\mathbb Q$ but neither open nor closed in $\mathbb R$ looks correct to me; both can be seen looking at (small enough) neighbourhoods of points in $S$ and $S^c$

Comment: In your first paragraph I notice that you are careful to say either "*open in $\mathbb Q$*" or "*open in $\mathbb R$*" as appropriate. But you have dropped that care in your second paragraph, and so your question becomes rather unclear.

Comment: Set of Irrational numbers is dense in $(\Bbb{R}, \tau_{euclidean}) $ i.e any non empty open set must contain a irrational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "proof" that $S$ is open is strange and confusingly written. You write the sentence

> And we can not find any point in the set that does not contain any points of that set.

which makes no sense at all. How could a point contain points? What does that sentence even mean?

---

There is a reason why mathematical proofs are written in a rigorous manner, and that reason is traceability. A mathematical proof needs to have steps which are verifiably correct. Basically, a proof is just a series of statements, where each statement either follows from previous statements, or is an assumption. Your argument is of no such shape, and is therefore not a proof at all.

In fact, the set $S$ is not open in $\mathbb R$, and it is easy to prove that.

In order for the set to be open in $\mathbb R$, the following would need to hold:

> For every $x\in S$, there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)\subseteq \S$.

The above statement can easily be disproven. Take $x=0\in S$. Then let $\epsilon >0$ be arbitrary. Then, take $x_0 = \frac{\pi}{n}$, where $n$ is some integer bigger than $\frac\pi\epsilon$. Because $n>\frac\pi\epsilon$, we know that $\epsilon > \frac\pi n$, which means that $\frac\pi n\in(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$.

However, we also know that $\frac\pi n$ is not a rational number, and therefore, $\frac\pi n$ is not an element of $S$. Therefore, $(0-\epsilon,0+\epsilon)$ is **not** a subset of $S$, and because $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we know that the same is true for **all** $\epsilon > 0$, which means $S$ is not open.

Comment: Sorry It was a serious mistake. I apologize for my unclear statements. Actually I was thinking something else and typing something else. But I get it now why $S$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We show that $S$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$. This is equivalent to showing that $\mathbb{R}\setminus S$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$. Now set

$$\Omega=\mathbb{R}\setminus S=\mathbb{R}\setminus((-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})\cap\mathbb{Q})=(-\infty,-\sqrt{2}]\cup I \cup[\sqrt{2},\infty),$$

where $I=(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})\cap(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})$, i.e. the irrationals in $(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$. Now as the irrationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, $I$ is dense in $(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$. We can thus choose a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $I$ with limit $x\in S$. Then $x\notin\Omega$, and as $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ was in $\Omega$, it follows that $\Omega$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$. Thus $S=\mathbb{R}\setminus\Omega$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$.